# Photoshop JSX create SmartObject at original size

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

I've written a script to lay out a bunch of artboards based on a folder of images with most artboards containing multiple images, including masks and shadows. I'm trying to save all the art layers on an artboard as a SmartObject, but when I select all the layers on a particular artboard and run

```
    var idnewPlacedLayer = stringIDToTypeID( 'newPlacedLayer' );
    executeAction(idnewPlacedLayer, undefined, DialogModes.NO);
```

I end up with a scaled SO, ie, by making the SO, the images inside are scaled down. the images themselves are imported as smartObjects, but maintain the original dimensions. I tried

```
app.activeDocument.layerSets[k].layers[g].resize(100 ,100,AnchorPosition.MIDDLECENTER);
```

as I select each layer, but it didn't do anything. Is there a way to ensure that the new SO is the same pixel size of the component images?

Comment: Converting to SO doesn't change scale of anything and keeps the pixel size — my guess the problem is somewhere else. Also your `resize()` didn't do anything because it resizes _relatively_, so resizing to relative 100% is leaving the layer the same size.

Comment: [This post](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem/how-can-i-capture-a-smart-object-s-original-dimension-via-scripts/m-p/9679330#M149408) might be of use! Good luck